# How to make only part of the text bold

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

Can you tell me how I can make only part of the text bold:

```
TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();        
        dataPane.appendText("Product Version: " + "1.0");
        dataPane.appendText("\nJava: " + "7");
        dataPane.appendText("\nRuntime: " + "7");
        dataPane.appendText("\nSystem: " + "Linux");
        dataPane.appendText("\nUser directory: " + "/home/dir");
```

I want to make only these strings bold: `Product Version, Java, Runtime, System, User directory`? What will be the easiest way to do this?

***UPDATE***

I also tested this code:

TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();

```
    dataPane.setPrefRowCount(10);
    Text wd = new Text("Version");
    wd.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));

    dataPane.appendText(wd + "1.0");
    dataPane.appendText("\nJava: " + "7");
    dataPane.appendText("\nRuntime: " + "7");
    dataPane.appendText("\nSystem: " + "Linux");
    dataPane.appendText("\nUser directory: " + "/home/dir");
```

I get this: `Text@149e84241.0`

The text is not properly formatted.

Comment: It is not possible with TextArea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an editor pane with the content type set to html instead of a text area. I threw an editor pane into a scratch project really quick and just used the default variable names and object properties. Here's how I produced what I believe you're looking for:

```
jEditorPane1.setContentType("text/html"); //by default this is text/plain
//use margin-top and margin-bottom to prevent gaps between paragraphs
//or actually customize them to create space if you desire so
jEditorPane1.setText("<p style='margin-top:0pt;'><b>Product Version:</b> 1.0</p>" + 
    "<p style='margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt;'><b>Java:</b> 7</p>" +
    "<p style='margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt;'><b>Runtime:</b> 7</p>" +
    "<p style='margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt;'><b>System:</b> Linux</p>" +
    "<p style='margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt;'><b>User directory:</b> /home/dir</p>");
```